# Hybrid drive not booting faster than a normal HD

Tags: hybrid-storage

I have used Windows 7 to create an image of my existing standard 160GB HD and copied this image back to a bigger 500GB Seagate hybrid drive. After copying the image to the hybrid I had to resize the partition, which was fine but after rebooting a few times to "teach" the hybrid, I have no increase in boot speed. It still takes 20-25 seconds to close down and then over a minute to start up.

Is this something to do with the way the image lays itself on the drive indiscriminately? Do I need to load the OS on the drive from scratch to get the benefits?

My PC with an i5 processor, is using AHCI mode.

Comment: It should only take 3 boot ups for it to cache the boot files, unfortunately Seagate does not have diagnostic tools specially for the Hybrid drives, I would call Seagate support and see what excuses they throw at you.

Comment: System (boot) performance is not determined merely by your CPU and hard drive. It is hard to even guess about where your "bottleneck" may be  without knowing other factors such as how much RAM you have, what chipset/motherboard you are using, and even which i5 you are using. You also provided no details on what start & stop times you have picked to determine how much time it takes for your system to start up.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a 500GB drive it's going to be the first generation Momentus XT drive.

And since that's the case, you may be expecting too much of a boost, especially by-way of system boot times.

Consider what is said about the 750GB *second generation* Momentus XTs:

> The ST750LX003 sports two firmware-based improvements compared to its
>   predecessor. First, the company says that it now permanently pins
>   system files associated with the boot process into cache, speeding
>   that up substantially. We can confirm that this works; Windows 7
>   starts up in the time we're used to seeing from popular many popular
>   SSDs.

Apparently this due to their new "FAST" system (Flash-Assisted Storage Technology), including the specific "FAST Factor Boot", that wasn't in the first generation drives:

> FAST Factor boot enables systems to boot and be productive with speeds
>   similar to SSD or several times faster than traditional HDDs.

and

> The FAST Factor™ advantage takes the Momentus XT drive to a new level
>   by enhancing data integrity and increasing storage longevity.
>
> - Boots and performs like an SSD
> - Up to 3× faster than a traditional HDD
> - SATA 6Gb/s with NCQ for interface speed

Sources:

- [Momentus XT 750 GB Review: A Second-Gen Hybrid Hard Drive](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/hybrid-hard-drive-flash-ssd,3116.html)
- [New Seagate Momentus XT Hybrid drive (SSD and HDD)](http://storageioblog.com/?p=2312)
- [Seagate's Momentus XT Solid State Hybrid Drive page](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/laptop-hard-drives/momentus-xt-hybrid/)